# Why is the `object.size` of an environment smaller than the `object.size` of the objects in the environment?

Tags: r, rlang

I ran into a confusing situation while writing a function factory. I have a tibble with columns of identifying information, and a list column containing data.

```r
tib <-
    tibble(
        id_1 = letters[1:3],
        id_2 = LETTERS[1:3],
        data = list(mtcars, iris, volcano)
    )
```

I created a function factory to make it easy to get the datasets stored in this tibble.

```r
data_getter <- function(data) {
    force(data)
    function(id_1, id_2) {
        where <- data$id_1 == id_1 & data$id_2 == id_2
        data[where, ]$data %>% 
            purrr::flatten_df()
    }
}

get_from_tib <- data_getter(tib)
```

In reality, the data frame I am working with is very large. My understanding is that `get_from_tib` captures an environment that includes `tib`. I was worried when I did this that by duplication of this large dataset, I would start to run out of memory. However, I was very surprised when the `object.size` of my function was smaller than the dataset that is supposedly captured by it!

```
object.size(tib)
21752 bytes

object.size(get_from_tib)
8416 bytes
```

This works even If I delete `tib` from the working environment

```r
rm(tib)

object.size(get_from_tib)
8416 bytes
```

Why is the environment so much smaller? Is `object.size` simply the wrong function for getting the size of all objects contained in an environment?

### Reprex below

```r
library(magrittr)

tib <-
    dplyr::tibble(
        id_1 = letters[1:3],
        id_2 = LETTERS[1:3],
        data = list(mtcars, iris, USArrests)
    )


data_getter <- function(data) {
    force(data)
    function(id_1, id_2) {
        where <- data$id_1 == id_1 & data$id_2 == id_2
        data[where, ]$data %>% 
            purrr::flatten_df()
    }
}

get_from_tib <- data_getter(tib)

get_from_tib('c', 'C')
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Murder Assault UrbanPop  Rape
#>     <dbl>   <int>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1   13.2     236       58  21.2
#>  2   10       263       48  44.5
#>  3    8.1     294       80  31  
#>  4    8.8     190       50  19.5
#>  5    9       276       91  40.6
#>  6    7.9     204       78  38.7
#>  7    3.3     110       77  11.1
#>  8    5.9     238       72  15.8
#>  9   15.4     335       80  31.9
#> 10   17.4     211       60  25.8
#> # … with 40 more rows


object.size(tib)
#> 21752 bytes
object.size(get_from_tib)
#> 8416 bytes


rm(tib)
object.size(get_from_tib)
#> 8416 bytes
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the part in the `?object.size` help page that says

> Associated space (e.g., the environment of a function and what the pointer in a EXTPTRSXP points to) is not included in the calculation.

The `data` variable is captured in a closure; it's not really "in" the code of the function that's returned from `data_getter`.

The `pyry::object_size()` funciton does a better of job of taking the enclosing environment into consideration as well.

```
pryr::object_size(tib)
# 21 kB
pryr::object_size(get_from_tib)
# 26.9 kB
```